# Create columns in a dataframe as a sum of previous columns for a bar chart race visualization in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate tax payments, made by companies each year, and show the sum of totally paid taxes after each year, using previous years and summarizing them.

After doing this, I want to show [bar chart race](https://emilykuehler.github.io/bar-chart-race/) (but this is beyond my question, just a clarification what I want).

I did it in a very rough manual way, using `mutate`.

This solution is terrible, I acknowledge and I would like to learn a more elegant way (especially with `dplyr`). I did my research, but did not find how to do it, maybe asking a wrong question in my search.

```
company_payments_clean %>% mutate(Sum2007 = `2006` + `2007`,
                                      Sum2008 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008`, 
                                      Sum2009 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009`,
                                      Sum2010 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010`,
                                      Sum2011 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010` + `2011`,
                                      Sum2012 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010` + `2011` + `2012`,
                                      Sum2013 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010` + `2011` + `2012` + `2013`,
                                      Sum2014 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010` + `2011` + `2012` + `2013` + `2014`,
                                      Sum2015 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010` + `2011` + `2012` + `2013` + `2014` + `2015`,
                                      Sum2016 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010` + `2011` + `2012` + `2013` + `2014` + `2015` + `2016`,
                                      Sum2017 = `2006` + `2007` + `2008` + `2009` + `2010` + `2011` + `2012` + `2013` + `2014` + `2015` + `2016` + `2017`) %>%
                                      select(`Name of organisation`, Sum2007, Sum2008, Sum2009, Sum2010, Sum2011, Sum2012, Sum2013, Sum2014, Sum2015, Sum2016, Sum2017)
```

My data looks like this (this is an open data, which is available online)

```
structure(list(`Name of organisation` = c("?????? ??? ???", "??????? ?????????", 
"????????? ????", "????n Erch", "ADAE", "Adamas mauntin"), `2006` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2007` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2008` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `2009` = c(0, 0, 63791000, 736145300, 0, 0), `2010` = c(42064000, 
0, 0, 511734500, 0, 188945000), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 841354900, 
0, 0), `2012` = c(0, 0, 0, 1603328000, 0, 0), `2013` = c(0, 0, 
417182450, 289145100, 0, 197865350), `2014` = c(0, 0, 214928280, 
102937500, 0, 0), `2015` = c(104671449, 0, 0, 0, 175549000, 0
), `2016` = c(141311733.57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2017` = c(150181688.63, 
124363263, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
`Name of organisation` = c("?????? ??? ???", "??????? ?????????", 
"????????? ????", "????n Erch", "ADAE", "Adamas mauntin"), 
.rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please advise!

Comment: It might be easier if you put all your years in one column(`tidyr::gather`/`tidyr::pivot_longer`). Otherwise,  having separate columns for each year makes it harder and less efficient to manipulate the data.

Comment: Yes, of course, but this was done intentionally, because the visualization will be done not in R, but using another tool, which requires such structure specifically.

Comment: You can always do the manipulations and change the data back to the wide structure. Or you could write a function and `map_at`/apply it at specific columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply `apply()` `cumsum()`.

```
t(apply(company_payments_clean[-1], MARGIN=1, cumsum))
```

For the `barplot()`, `rownames` are appropriate, since we could use them for the colors and the legend. Here a basic bar chart:

```
dat <- `rownames<-`(
  t(apply(company_payments_clean[-1], MARGIN=1, cumsum)),
  company_payments_clean[[1]]
)

b <- barplot(dat, horiz=TRUE, col=2:7, yaxt="n")
mtext(colnames(dat), 2, at=b, las=1)
legend("bottomright", col=2:7, pch=15, rownames(dat), bty="n", cex=.9)
```

[image]

**Note:** If you need company as an extra column, instead of `rownames<-` just combine them with the `apply` result into a new `data.frame`.

```
dat1 <- cbind.data.frame(`Name of organisation`=company_payments_clean[[1]], 
                        t(apply(company_payments_clean[-1], MARGIN=1, cumsum)))

dat1[, 1:7]
#   Name of organisation 2006 2007 2008      2009       2010       2011
# 1       ?????? ??? ???    0    0    0         0   42064000   42064000
# 2    ??????? ?????????    0    0    0         0          0          0
# 3       ????????? ????    0    0    0  63791000   63791000   63791000
# 4           ????n Erch    0    0    0 736145300 1247879800 2089234700
# 5                 ADAE    0    0    0         0          0          0
# 6       Adamas mauntin    0    0    0         0  188945000  188945000
```

You also could do both :)

Comment: Thanks, a great option, the only problem here - it drops the first column with the company name.

Comment: @Oleksiy Do you need them as an extra column or as rownames?

Comment: I need them instead of given 2006-2017 ideally. That is why after mutating I used `%>% select` to choose only newly created columns and the name of the organization.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to get the same results as what you did above, as we can do the analysis on the long data and easily pivot it back to the wide format you need for your plot. I made sure to sort the data by year in case it isn't always in your final dataset.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

company_payments_clean %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -`Name of organisation`, names_to = "year") %>%
  group_by(`Name of organisation`) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(tax_sum = cumsum(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -value,
              names_from = year,
              names_prefix = "Sum",
              values_from = tax_sum)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I prefer tidyverse code. But still used `gather` to deal with this code :)